# index string has no method of isin()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with index is string name like 'apple' etc.

Now I have a list

name_list=['apple','orange','tomato']

I'd like to filter dataframe rows by selecting rows with index is in the above list

```
df=df.loc[df.index.str.isin(name_list)]
```

then I got an error of

```
AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.index.isin`, not `df.index.str.isin`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.isin(name_list)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `reindex`

```
df = df.reindex(name_list)
```